# Jquery Mobile, add tap delay

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I've recently moved over to Jquery mobile for my Phonegap app as the 300ms webkit click delay was too much of a delay, I now however have the opposite issue,

I'm working on what is essentially a pin pad with 10 digits, If a user taps on them in quick succession it is occasionally triggering the pin event twice. each of my pin buttons are div's
e.g.

```
<div class='grid'>
        <div class="flexone"><div class="pin-num">1</div></div>
        <div class="flexone"><div class="pin-num">2</div></div>
        <div class="flexone"><div class="pin-num">3</div></div>
</div>
```

on each tap I then run the following function

```
$('.pin-num').on("tap", function(){
        var pin = $(this).text();
        updatePin(pin);
});
```

which in turn triggers the following function

```
function updatePin(pin) {

                var count = "0";
                if($('.psone').text() != "") { count++; }
                if($('.pstwo').text() != "") { count++; }
                if($('.psthree').text() != "") { count++; }
                if($('.psfour').text() != "") { count++; }

                if(count == "0") { hideStatus(); $('.ph').text(""); $('.psone').text(pin); $('.psone').attr("pin", pin); $('.pin-cancel').html('<img class="pin-back" src="img/back.png">');  }
                if(count == "1") { $('.psone').text("•"); $('.pstwo').text(pin); $('.pstwo').attr("pin", pin);}
                if(count == "2") { $('.pstwo').text("•"); $('.psthree').text(pin); $('.psthree').attr("pin", pin); }
                if(count == "3") { $('.psthree').text("•"); $('.psfour').text("•"); $('.psfour').attr("pin", pin); checkPin();  }
                if(count == "4") { $('.psone').text(pin); $('.pstwo').text(""); $('.psthree').text(""); $('.psfour').text(""); hideStatus(); $('.pin-cancel').html('<img class="pin-back" src="img/back.png">'); }

            }
```

What I need to do is to be able to not allowed two tap events to trigger within x miliseconds of each other, I'm guessing some where around 30ms should stop the accidental trigger.

I've search the web and can't find anything related, just issues with removing the delay. Could anyone advise how they would approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$('.pin-num').on("tap", function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var pin = $(this).text();
        updatePin(pin);
});
```